# How to rescale widgets in a layout?

Tags: c++, layout, qt4, widget

I have a widget (lets call it a main widget), which should display another two widgets. I am using [QGridLayout](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.5/qgridlayout.html) to position these two widgets in the main widget. (This is just simplified. I really got 5 widgets in the main window)

Initially, these two widgets are of the same size, but they can rescale. For example, the 2nd widget should be displayed 2, 3 or 4 times bigger as the 1st widget, but both should be displayed.

Something like this :
[image]

I tried using [addWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2), with stretching the 2nd widget over rows and columns, but that didn't work as expected (the widget's sizes remained the same)

So, how would you suggest me to achieve as requested?
If QGridLayout is not the right class, what should I use?

**EDIT:**

Some types:
    ...
    struct info
    {
      int item;
      int row;
      int column;
      int rowSpan;
      int columnSpan;
    }
    typedef std::vector< info > LayoutDefinition;
    ...

The class WindowsContainer contains this :

```
vector< QWidget* > containers;
```

Here is the method that updates the layout:

```
void WindowsContainer::SetNewLayout( const LayoutDefinition & newLayoutDef )
{
    // hide all containers
    for ( std::vector< QWidget* >::iterator it = containers.begin(); containers.end() != it; ++ it )
    {
        (*it)->hide();
    }

    // remove all items in the layout, and release the layout
    QLayout * currentLayout( layout() );
    if ( 0 != currentLayout )
    {
        // remove all items in the layout
        // (this code is taken from the reference page for the QLayout::takeAt() function)
        QLayoutItem *child;
        while ( ( child = currentLayout->takeAt( 0 ) ) != 0 )
        {
            delete child;
        }
    }
    delete( currentLayout );

    // form the new layout
    QGridLayout *newLayout = new QGridLayout( this );
    newLayout->setSpacing( 0 );
    newLayout->setContentsMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0 );

    for ( LayoutDefinition::const_iterator it = newLayoutDef.begin(); newLayoutDef.end() != it; ++ it )
    {
            QWidget * w( containers.at( it->item ) );

            newLayout->addWidget( w,
                                it->row,
                                it->column,
                                it->rowSpan,
                                it->columnSpan
                                );
            w->show();
    }

    // update the layout of this object
    setLayout( newLayout );
}
```

It all works, until I try to set rowSpan and columnSpan. Both images still occupy the same area size.

I also tried with spacers, and that didn't work (not sure if I did it correctly).

Comment: You will have to describe the process of how you want the change to happen I think.  This should be possible, though.

Comment: @TomKerr Why does it matter? Lets say there is a button somewhere, which should set the layout in such a way that the top image is 1/4 of the bottom image. There is another button, which sets 1:1 ration. And the 3rd button, which sets ratio 4:1

Comment: If you wanted to allow the user to drag a separator, you could use the docking widgets in the main window for instance.  That would be a very different solution to adjusting size policies and stretch factors of your grid programatically generated from some internal event.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be accomplished with layouts, spacers and size policies. Here is a screen shot from QtCreator that reproduces the effect you are looking for:

[image]

The "TopWidget" will occupy as little space as necessary as dictated by the widgets it contains and the "BottomWidget" will expand to occupy all remaining space when the application window is resized.

The "BottomWidget" has both horizontal and vertical size policies set to "expanding".

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it : it is enough to set the stretch factors.

In the above example :

```
for ( LayoutDefinition::const_iterator it = newLayoutDef.begin(); newLayoutDef.end() != it; ++ it )
    {
            QWidget * w( containers.at( it->item ) );

            newLayout->addWidget( w, it->row, it->column );
            w->show();
    }
    newLayout->setRowStretch( 0, 1 );
    newLayout->setRowStretch( 1, 2 );
```

This will cause the 2nd row to be two times bigger then the 1st row.

Answer (score -4):

It's impossible. Layout is a thingy that is supposed to automatically manage layout and size of widgets. Write your own layout.

Comment: *Write your own layout.* - Do you mean a new layout class which inherits from QLayout?

Comment: Exactly. or you can just inherit from QGridLayout and redefine only those methods that are enough to achieve desired effect.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate at all.

Comment: This is not true. While it is true that part of the job of a layout is to manage the size of widgets it contain, the position of those widgets can be influenced through the use of combining layouts, spacers and size policies of the widgets etc. @V Jovic: If possible, becoming familiar with Qt Designer for designing your interfaces will save you tons of time in the long run. It makes designing and maintaining UI much easier and faster.